# How I can delete comments from a Youtube video through api?

Tags: youtube-api

I've been looking through the documentation of Google Youtube API in v2 and v3 versions how to delete users comments to a video posted on youtube by API and I could not find information.

You can perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Using V3 API, it's a simple DELETE HTTP request.

> HTTP request
>
> DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments

With the comment to be delete passed in parameter:

> **id**
>
> The id parameter specifies the comment ID for the resource
>   that is being deleted.

On success, the method returns an HTTP 204 response code.

The request requires proper authorization.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete